# what is the range of Blutooth? and how it can receive the orders from more than one mobile?

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking

If i have one Bluetooth how it can receive orders from more than one mobile or more than one user?
And what is the range of Bluetooth ?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth signals often have a range of approximately **10 meters**.

As to how they work...

> Bluetooth uses a technique called spread-spectrum frequency hopping that makes it rare for more than one device to be transmitting on the same frequency at the same time. In this technique, a device will use 79 individual, randomly chosen frequencies within a designated range, changing from one to another on a regular basis. In the case of Bluetooth, the transmitters change frequencies 1,600 times every second, meaning that more devices can make full use of a limited slice of the radio spectrum. Since every Bluetooth transmitter uses spread-spectrum transmitting automatically, it’s unlikely that two transmitters will be on the same frequency at the same time.

**Source:** [HowStuffWorks](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/bluetooth2.htm).